# How to install nvm in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nvm

I'm trying to install nvm within a Dockerfile.  It seems like it installs OK, but the `nvm` command is not working.

Dockerfile:

```
# Install nvm
RUN git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /root/.nvm;
RUN chmod -R 777 /root/.nvm/;
RUN sh /root/.nvm/install.sh;
RUN export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm";
RUN echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc;
RUN nvm ls-remote;
```

Build output:

```
Step 23/39 : RUN git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /root/.nvm;
 ---> Running in ca485a68b9aa
Cloning into '/root/.nvm'...
 ---> a6f61d486443
Removing intermediate container ca485a68b9aa
Step 24/39 : RUN chmod -R 777 /root/.nvm/
 ---> Running in 6d4432926745
 ---> 30e7efc5bd41
Removing intermediate container 6d4432926745
Step 25/39 : RUN sh /root/.nvm/install.sh;
 ---> Running in 79b517430285
=> Downloading nvm from git to '$HOME/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '$HOME/.nvm'...
* (HEAD detached at v0.33.0)
  master
=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.profile
=> bash_completion source string already in /root/.profile
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.9.5
npm info ok
=> Installing Node.js version 6.9.5
Downloading and installing node v6.9.5...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v6.9.5 (npm v3.10.10)
Creating default alias: default -> 6.9.5 (-> v6.9.5 *)
/root/.nvm/install.sh: 136: [: v6.9.5: unexpected operator
Failed to install Node.js 6.9.5
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
 ---> 9f6f3e74cd19
Removing intermediate container 79b517430285
Step 26/39 : RUN export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm";
 ---> Running in 1d768138e3d5
 ---> 8039dfb4311c
Removing intermediate container 1d768138e3d5
Step 27/39 : RUN echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc;
 ---> Running in d91126b7de62
 ---> 52313e09866e
Removing intermediate container d91126b7de62
Step 28/39 : RUN nvm ls-remote;
 ---> Running in f13c1ed42b3a
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c nvm ls-remote;' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The error:

```
Step 28/39 : RUN nvm ls-remote;
 ---> Running in f13c1ed42b3a
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c nvm ls-remote;' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The end of my /root/.bashrc file looks like:

```
[[ -s /root/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /root/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Everything else in the Dockerfile works.  Adding the nvm stuff is what broke it.  [Here is the full file.](http://pastebin.com/f6YhKmQ2)

Comment: First error points to [line 136 of `install.sh`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/install.sh#L136) which has some weird, nested double-quotes. I'm no bash expert but that looks wrong to me

Comment: Also feel free to give a working Dockerfile (including your base image if possible) so we can reproduce and help.

Comment: @kytwb - here's the full Dockerfile http://pastebin.com/f6YhKmQ2

Comment: Ever use `n`? I've always liked it better then nvm, and it always works. https://github.com/tj/n

Comment: @BretFisher Software alternatives are not an option in this case.

Comment: Also, it's a bit of an anti-pattern to put a node version program in your container. The standard pattern is to install a specific node version, and if you need to vary that for different builds, use an ENV to specify the version, like they do in the official node repo https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/90d5e3df903b830d039d3fe8f30e3a62395db37e/7.5/Dockerfile#L22-L29 or you can do something similar with node source packages rather then building from source: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Comment: You can't have more then one CMD in your dockerfile

Comment: You install node, and then are trying to install nvm?  Do you need two versions of node or something?

Comment: Lastly, what you likely want to do is split this dockerfile up. You'll want one for the php app and one for db at minimum. Then you can use the official repos of each and build on that. Use docker-compose to launch/link them together.

Comment: what is you base image ?

Comment: Try, `RUN source ~/.bashrc && nvm ls-remote;` instead of `RUN nvm ls-remote;`

Comment: @BretFisher I'll remove those extra CMD.  I do not have the option to use more than one Dockerfile in this case though, so docker-compose is out of the question.  Alternatively I could have my own base images based off of each other but for now one Dockerfile is easier to work with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made the following changes to your Dockerfile to make it work:

First, replace...

```
RUN sh /root/.nvm/install.sh;
```

...with:

```
RUN bash /root/.nvm/install.sh;
```

Why? On Redhat-based systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`. But on [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`. And this is what happens with `dash`:

```
root@52d54205a137:/# bash -c '[ 1 == 1 ] && echo yes!'
yes!
root@52d54205a137:/# dash -c '[ 1 == 1 ] && echo yes!'
dash: 1: [: 1: unexpected operator
```

Second, replace...

```
RUN nvm ls-remote;
```

...with:

```
RUN bash -i -c 'nvm ls-remote';
```

Why? Because, the default .bashrc for a user in Ubuntu (almost at the top) contains:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

And the source-ing of nvm's scripts takes place at the bottom. So we need to make sure that bash is invoked interactively by passing the argument `-i`.

Third, you could skip the following lines in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm";
RUN echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc;
```

Why? Because `bash /root/.nvm/install.sh;` will automatically do it for you:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker run --rm -it 2a283d6e2173 tail -2 /root/.bashrc
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 2):

**Instalation** of **nvm** on ubuntu in **dockerfile**

In the case of Ubuntu 20.04 you can use only these commands and everything will be alright

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update -y &&  apt upgrade -y && apt install wget bash -y

RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

RUN bash -i -c 'nvm ls-remote'
```

hopefully it will work